# C++ - std::initializer_list vs std::span

Tags: c++, c++20

What is the difference between ***std::initializer_list*** and ***std::span***? Both are contiguous sequences of values of some type. Both are non-owning.
So when do we use the first and when do we use the latter?

Comment: Where did you hear that `std::initializer_list` is non-owning? It's "owning" in the sense that the lifetime of the underlying array basically copies the lifetime of the initializer list object (simply said).

Comment: This implementation of span aims to follow the C++20 proposal as closely as possible, in order to make it easy for people to switch to `std::span` when they upgrade to '20 (the `make_span()` functions are a temporary workaround for the lack of CTAD before '17). C++20's span doesn't provide a separate constructor or deduction guide for `std::initializer_list.`

Comment: You can use `span` to "view" for example some subsequence of vector's elements. How would you do this with `initilizer_list`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is that `std::initializer_list<T>` is used to *create* a new range, for the purposes of initialization. While `std::span<T>` is used to *refer* to existing ranges, for better APIs.

---

`std::initializer_list<T>` is a language feature that actually constructs a new array and owns it. It solves the problem of how to conveniently initialize containers:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct vector {
    vector(std::initializer_list<T>);
};

vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

That creates a `std::initializer_list<int>` on the fly containing the four integers there, and passes it into `vector` so that it can construct itself properly.

This is really the only place `std::initializer_list<T>` should be used: either constructors or function parameters to pass a range in on the fly, for convenience (unit tests are a common place that desires such convenience).

---

`std::span<T>` on the other hand is used to *refer* to an existing range. Its job is to replace functions of the form:

```cpp
void do_something(int*, size_t);
```

with

```cpp
void do_something(std::span<int>);
```

Which makes such functions generally easier to use and safer. `std::span` is constructible from any appropriate contiguous range, so taking our example from earlier:

```cpp
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
do_something(v); // ok
```

It can also be used to replace functions of the form:

```cpp
void do_something_else(std::vector<unsigned char> const&);
```

Which can only be called with, specifically, a `vector`, with the more general:

```cpp
void do_something_else(std::span<unsigned char const>);
```

Which can be called with any backing contiguous storage over `unsigned char`.

With `span` you have to be careful, since it's basically a reference that just doesn't get spelled with a `&`, but it is an extremely useful type.

Answer (score 4):

The principle differences between the two are how the language treats them. Or more specifically, how it *doesn't* in the case of a `span`.

You cannot create an `initializer_list` from an existing container object or array. They can only be created by copying from other `initializer_list`s or from a braced-init-list (ie: `{ stuff }`). That is, the *compiler* governs the creation of an `initializer_list` and the array it points into.

Similarly, a constructor that takes only an `initializer_list` has special meaning to the compiler. When performing list initialization on that type, such constructors are given priority in overload resolution. `span` is given no special meaning by the compiler.

`initializer_list` also has lifetime rules that are different from `span`. The lifetime of the array pointed to by an `initializer_list` is the lifetime of the `initializer_list` object that was created from a `braced-init-list`. This is not true of `span`; the lifetime of a `span` created from a container is whatever you say it is based on how you use it in code.

Broadly speaking, you should only use `initializer_list` when you're *initializing* an object.

Comment: Can you provide a reliable sources for "only use initializer_list when you're initializing an object."? I looked through Stroustrup and CoreGuidelines and didn't find any.

Comment: @КоеКто: The source is me. It's my rule; you can decide for yourself if you agree or not.

Answer (score -1):

One difference is that std::span can be used dynamically, unlike std::initializer_list.

Comment: Note that a good answer of this kind would at least provide some code example of the statement.