# Is std::span a view?

Tags: c++, std, c++20, std-span

Is `std::span` a view?

My speculation stems from the fact that it does not "own".

I have read that it is a reference to ranges [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65507610/c-stdinitializer-list-vs-stdspan) and that it "[just wraps](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span)" I have not seen anywhere been stated explicitly that it is a view.

Comment: It probably can be considered as a view since it's just a *pointer* + a *size*. Although it allows you to modify the source. So it's not exactly similar to e.g. `string_view`.

Comment: I am not an expert in this terminology, but it has been shared in respectable circles that "a view can not modify".  For some definition of "view".

Comment: @DrewDormannD [What is a `view`?](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2415r2.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally span is a [reference-like class type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45723820/4885321).

As for "view": is this related to what you're asking? ([source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span))

```
template<class T, std::size_t Extent> inline constexpr bool
ranges::enable_view<std::span<T, Extent>> = true;
```

> This specialization of ranges::enable_view makes span satisfy view.